# How to find out what the timeout is for our ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

I've read other posts that say the timeout is defined by the sessionState attribute in the Web.config. However, in my case, it looks like it is set to 10 minutes, yet the page/session does not expire after 10 minutes.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"  
              stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
              sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password="
              cookieless="false" 
              timeout="10"/>
```

The portion of the site in question is outside our standard login url, so I know that Forms Authentication should not be playing a role here.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name="Auth" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1000"/>
</authentication>
```

Lastly, I don't think the httpRuntime should be playing a role either because the sessionState timeout value is much more restrictive in this case.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="36000" maxRequestLength="10240" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Yet after all this, the page does not seem to expire/timeout. In other words, after waiting 10 minutes, even 20 minutes while idling, I then try to navigate to another page or perform an action on the page and everything seems to continue as if there is no timeout set.

I also put a breakpoint on Page_Load event to see what the Session.Timeout property is, and it says 10 minutes as well. However, this is obviously not true as after 10 minutes, the page and session appear to be going strong.

Comment: Try using `UseCookies` instead of false for `cookieless`. (May or may not help: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).)

Comment: Also try setting your auth timeout to *less* than the session, so auth isn't triggering an 'ok to continue'. (Just in case.)

Comment: @wazz thanks, tried both suggestions with no effect.